# Load array of values in a plot (Android studio)

Tags: tags, androidplot

I am having some dificulty loading 2 arrays of values inside a plot using androidPlot library.
Here is my code:

```
 plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.plot);
        Number[] IMC3 = {results2[0]};
        Number[] DATA = {results[0]};

       // Number[] DATA3 = {results[0]};

        // create our series from our array of nums:
        XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
                Arrays.asList(IMC3), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series1");
        XYSeries series2 = new SimpleXYSeries(
                Arrays.asList(DATA), SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "Series1");


        LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, null);

        plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);
```

I have tried a few ways but i can't load the 2 arrays as X and Y. What I want is X axis with DATA and Y axis with IMC3 but i can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

An XYSeries in Androidplot includes both x and y values, so you need to use the SimpleXYSeries constructor that takes both together:

```
XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(DATA), Arrays.asList(IMC3), "Series1");
```